Fixing shallow holes in paint, left by removing tape or glue from the walls
While removing different kinds of tapes and glues from the wall, some pieces of paint and plaster came out.
I'm able to apply plaster and sand it off, but not very skilled/precise at it. I don't know whether I should re-plaster all those dents, or only the deeper ones; whether I scrape away some pieces of the paint/plaster around or inside the dents.
What's the best way to cover up dents like the ones in these pictures?







All such imperfections might be visible after repainting, depending on wall finish and light conditions.
Wall finish: paints with any sheen (i.e., gloss, semi-gloss, satin; anything other than dead flat) will tend to show imperfections more.
Light conditions: oblique light (i.e. light shining across the surface rather than directly at it) will tend to show imperfections more.
I recommend using spackle rather than plaster. Most (but not all...) spackles are a plaster product but are designed for easy application with a smooth putty knife and can be sanded and painted after a short dry time. Make it mandatory to fine sand and prime all repair areas if you don't want to see them.

Yeah, I suspect the hardest part of these repairs will be matching the texture of the adjacent surfaces.
